# Using variables in SOAP request file in JMeter

Tags: soap, jmeter

In a JMeter (v2.13) test plan I have a SOAP/XML-RPC sampler. The SOAP request itself is loaded from a random file.

**Sample request**

```
<mySoapRequest>
  <value>555</value>
</mySoapRequest>
```

This works fine.

I would now like to replace this fixed value with a variable which is defined in JMeter, i.e.

```
<mySoapRequest>
  <value>${someValue}</value>
</mySoapRequest>
```

It seems as if JMeter does not resolve this variable. The actual SOAP request sent to the service does not contain `555` but `${someValue}`. Is there any workaround so that I could use variables in the file?

Answer (score 1):

That can be done using `FileToString` and `eval` functions.

For this XML,

```
<mySoapRequest>
  <value>${someValue}</value>
</mySoapRequest>
```

In the SOAP/XML RPC request Data section, use the functions as shown below to get the value replaced at run time.

```
${__eval(${__FileToString(C:\users\me\desktop\soap.xml)})}
```

[__FileToString](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) - The FileToString function can be used to read an entire file. Each time it is called it reads the entire file.

[__eval](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval) - The eval function returns the result of evaluating a string expression.